# SQL Sever Management Studio 2008 does not let me back up my database

Tags: security, backup, sql-server, sql, sql-server-2008

I tried to back up a server I created in SQL Server, but I received the following message:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Backup failed for Server 'LAPTOP-6D0L83DV\SQLEXPRESS'. 
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.4000.0+((KJ_PCU_Main).120628-0827+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Backup+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Cannot open backup device
>   'C:\Users\Flight.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.4000.0+((KJ_PCU_Main).120628-0827+)&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

I failed to understand how to resolve this problem, and the added links were not of much help, either. I'll be extremely glad if someone could explain this to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have permission to access `C:\Users\Flight.bak`.
Specifically, the problem is probably with accessing `C:\Users\`,
where you need administrator permissions, so a non-administrator account
cannot write directly to that folder.

You should choose another folder, perhaps `C:\Users\YOUR-NAME` to which you have
full permissions. 
You could also create a folder named `C:\Users\YOUR-NAME\Backups`
or similar, or maybe create another folder on `C:\` to hold the backups.